# Mongoose wont insert an array when updating a model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model that consists of boards and lists like Trello,my model is

```
const listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    header: String,
    listItems: [String]
})

const BoardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    lists: [listSchema]
})
```

After a user creates a board and redirects to it, he should create a list then add items to that lists

```
module.exports.AddList = async(req, res) => {

    const { id } = req.body;
    Board.findById(id).then((board) => {
            const list = {
                header: "List1",
                listItem: ['task', 'task2']
            }
            board.lists.push(list);
            board.save();
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        })
}
```

When I do this it does insert a model into the database, but the lists[] only has the _id and header property, not listItems, what's the cause of this? And why does each object in the lists[] has its own _id when I cant use them such as

```
 List.findById('5f49b4db98bcad61a84410e6').then((list) => {
             console.log(list)
         })
```

just returns null;

Comment: Hey you using not using `await` keyword before `Board.findById(id)` query and again you can't update documents like pushing to result from the promise.

Comment: You are not using the `await` keyword before the mongoose query. Mongoose query return promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update document like this. Refer to the following documentation.
Now with the new syntax of `async-await`

```
module.exports.AddList = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.body;
    const board = await Board.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { header: "List1", listItem: ['task', 'task2'] } }, { new: true });
    //Do what to you want do with data.
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

You miss the `await` keyword before save()

```
module.exports.AddList = async(req, res) => {

    const { id } = req.body;
    Board.findById(id).then((board) => {
            const list = {
                header: "List1",
                listItem: ['task', 'task2']
            }
            board.lists.push(list);
            await board.save();
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        })
}
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Comment: this doesn't seem to add the array either

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do exactly? Your question is unclear